# How do I determine if my Toyota Camry 1994 LE has a 5S-FE or 1MZ-FE engine?

Tags: engine, toyota, camry

My car: Toyota Camry 1994 LE, 4 cyl, 4 door sedan. What is the type of the engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many cylinders does it have?  The 5S-FE is a straight four cylinder engine.  The 1MZ-FE is a V6 engine.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked your [VIN number](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Vehicle_Identification_Numbers_%28VIN_codes%29/Toyota/VIN_Codes#VIN_format_2009)?  There's a good chance that the [5th character](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Vehicle_Identification_Numbers_%28VIN_codes%29/Toyota/VIN_Codes#Engine) will answer your question: a `G` for a 5S-FE or an `F` for a 1MZ-FE.

Those codes are valid in the US after 1996.  Your mileage may vary depending on your location and from where the car was originally sourced.

Answer (score 1):

Some Toyota model of that vintage have a data plate on the firewall inside the engine compartment (my 1987 Land Cruiser have one) which list model number, paint color, transmission and engine number.

EDIT: 
[Here's the details](http://www.4crawler.com/4x4/ToyVIN.shtml) and seems that prior 1989 models have the engine model on the data plate:

[image]